# UPDATE statement on SQL Server table with non clustered index always split into INSERT followed by DELETE and not a direct UPDATE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When there is an UPDATE statement on the table with non clustered index and key columns are updated, we saw that there was INSERT of new row with updated values but DELETE of the old record didnt happen. Everyday UPDATE was happening correctly on the table. Only on  a particular day, there were INSERTs and DELETE didnt happen for an UPDATE. So just wanted to know if we can see in logs to know that this is how UPDATE is split and why the operation was not consistently completed. Can some one throw light on this aspect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpret what you saw. The insert/delete split is an implementation detail that is visible in the query plan. You can never have just one of the two. They are transactionally atomic.

If you do find such a case that would be an egregious bug in an incredibly well-tested and war-hardened part of SQL Server. Is is so unlikely that this actually happened.

More likely, your code has a bug. Or, some piece of code ran that you did not expect.

Or, you were reading from the database with `NOLOCK` and you saw the update partially completed. That's part of the reason `NOLOCK` is often not the best solution.

Comment: Also of note is that `NOLOCK` on `UPDATE` and `DELETE` is currently deprecated, and is on [the list of features being removed from the next version of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).  It's already not allowed on `INSERT`.  Beyond that, `SELECT` with `NOLOCK` can return duplicate or missing rows.  You really should only use `NOLOCK` with very great care and only when you know you don't care about completely accurate query results.